# Is there a reason for having a space after the Component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

For example, in the `App.tsx` file, where `App` is being called:

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

Is this just a practice? If so what is the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Do you mean as opposed to `<App/>`? It's just a style choice, see e.g. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/jsx-tag-spacing.md.

Comment: Ah alright, I was just wondering as i couldn't really find any answers on google. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is just a choice and varies depending on the person writing the code. It really doesn't matter if the space is there to not.

I personally like it.

Comment: So it doesn't affect the code itself? Alright, good to know. Thanks!